# Where does Deja-dup keep its config files?

Tags: 12.04, backup, deja-dup, duplicity

Deja-dup (now Ubuntu Backup) is just a GUI for duplicity, therefore it should store the config files somewhere. I would like to changed the backup volume size to something like 300MB and the increase the --full-if-older-than variable. is this possible?

Comment: At least in **Ubuntu 16.04** it's not in `~/.config/dconf` or `~/.gconf/apps/deja-dup/*`, and for those searching for the *dconf-editor* you must look for **SETTINGS EDITOR** instead.  It might be interesting for the ASKUbuntu Community to try to apply rules of OpenSource Community Philosophy, which means declare obsoleted or need to being confirm when a new version of Ubuntu is on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has changed in various **Déjà Dup** versions, but I believe it is currently at:

```
~/.gconf/apps/deja-dup/
```

What can't you change using the GUI front-end?

**UPDATE**

from: [launchpad.net: How do I also backup my deja Dup settings?](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/128181)

The settings used to be stored there, and the files are still present.

In more recent version they are stored in:

```
~/.config/dconf
```

Comment: I'd like to increase the volume size and be more conservative with full backups (once every 6 months or so). I checked the location you mention but I cannot find where this parameters are kept. Any ideas?

Comment: **Systems Settings >> Backup**, last tab: 'Schedule'

Comment: The settings are in file '~/.gconf/apps/deja-dup/%conf.xml', but that is only for experts.

Comment: So you cant change the volume size limit and the full backup time?

Comment: These are more likely to be settings in scripts (for Duplicity) that are used by Déjà Dup. see: https://live.gnome.org/DejaDup/HowItWorks OR https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto (I would need to do more research to answer better.)

Comment: Hi just the question I was after. I did move most of my home to a new computer. I want to move my DejaDup settings to the new machine as well. So I copied the above mentioned ``~/.gconf/apps/deja-dup/%conf.xml`` from the old to the new machine. In my settings I had quite a few folders to ignore. But the settings don't show up on the new machine. I've checked on my onld machine and this %conf.xml file does not change when I change the DejaDup settings. Any thoughts?

Comment: Check the directory, or copy all files (and sub-directories).  There is more than one settings file.

Comment: yes there are more files. I've copied all of them but my settings are not 100% the same as on the old machine?

Comment: Changed, in Answer.

Comment: The UI is inconvenient at best: it is very small and not resizable (12.04), and does not expose .* files/directories, many of which contain big caches or logs not needing to be backed up.

Answer (score 28):

The deja-dup settings can also be changed with `dconf-editor` in the `dconf-tools` apt package. The settings are in `org.gnome.DejaDup`.

Comment: +1 for best answer since Deja Dup / duplicity does not have its own config files anymore. Note: Schema org.gnome.DejaDup equals org > gnome > deja-dup in the dconf editor tree view :)

Comment: Great answer, though *caution*: Opening the "Backups" app in Ubuntu and closing it again may cause some settings to revert.  For example, using the `dconf-editor` I set backups to be kept at least 90 days (instead of the minimum available in the GUI app of 6 months).  When I opened the app, it showed 90 days. But when I closed it and re-opened, it had reverted to 6 months.

Comment: there is nothing there for me. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @LostCrotchet if you find them, please propose an edit or comment here and I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of using `dconf-editor`, you can use `gsettings` from command line.

- See all the options (keys) within the Deja-Dup schema, and their configurations:

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.DejaDup
  ```
- Edit keys:

  ```
  gsettings set SCHEMA [:PATH] KEY VALUE
  ```

  For example:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.DejaDup include-list ['$HOME']
  ```

Comment: I get: No such schema “org.gnome.DejaDup” when trying those commands, on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2):

fwiw, added a dconf setting if you build this from source, it will create a volsize setting in org.gnome.DejaDup.   you can change it to 500mb with dconf-editor.

[patched source code for deja-dup](https://code.launchpad.net/~peter-bsqt/deja-dup/volsize)

Comment: Amazing, the volume size of backup files is hardcoded! http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~peter-bsqt/deja-dup/volsize/revision/1548/libdeja/tools/duplicity/DuplicityJob.vala. So the answer to the actual question is: No, there is no config option.